# Deleting data table

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I am trying to delete a data table.

I have searched about how to do that and I think one way is to convert the data table into ranges and then delete them.

However, I could not find the Design tab, even after checking the box in options.

Even after I pulled the "Convert to range" function to the quick access bar, I still can't use it to convert data table into ranges.

Could you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want a Data Table created by what-if analysis (single variable / two variables). A Data Table is like a multicell array formula where you cannot change or delete just one cell. You need to select all cells in the table and hit delete.